# How to change name on Action bar when click on back button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to create an app. I am not getting name on Action bar. when go back to main activity from a fragment that moment we going back to main activity but name on action bar is not change showing Name of fragment after go to back on main activity  Using the following code-

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener{
 DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
 ListView mDrawerList;
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
 String mTitle="";
 private final String  TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    LatLng latLng;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    SupportMapFragment mFragment;
    Marker CurrentMarker,NearbyPlace,FindMarker;
    EditText editplace = null;
    Button findbtn = null;
    boolean firstRun = true;
    private Boolean exit = false;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //for connectivity service
    ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network is available ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        //.addTestDevice("abc")
        .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mFragment=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network is not available ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Fragment newFragment;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        newFragment = new NetworkCheck();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    editplace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editplace);
    findbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findbtn);

    setListnerOnWidget();

    mTitle = (String) getTitle();
    // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this,
        mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer,
        R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close){

            /** Called when drawer is closed */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            /** Called when a drawer is opened */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Select a menu");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
    };

    // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

    // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getBaseContext(),
        R.layout.drawer_list_item ,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu)
    );

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view,
            int position,
            long id) {
            displayView(position);
            // Updating the action bar title
            String[] menu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
            mTitle = menu[position];

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }

        private void displayView(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment newFragment;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:

                newFragment = new Help();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;

            case 1:

                newFragment = new ContactUs();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                break;

              case 2:
                  transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                try
                { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
                  i.setType("text/plain");
                  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
                  String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
                  sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iqwiner\n\n";
                  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);  
                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an action"));

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                { //e.toString();
                }   
                Log.e(TAG, "share button is clicked");
                break;

              case 3:
                newFragment = new Suggestion_Address();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                Log.e(TAG, "Suggestion Address button is clicked");
                break;

            }

        }

    });



}

private void setListnerOnWidget() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String location = editplace.getText().toString();
            if(location!=null && !location.equals("")){
                  new GeocoderTask().execute(location); 

                }
    }
    };
   findbtn.setOnClickListener(listener);

}



@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

//for back button 

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
         }
```

Please tell me how show name on action bar of main activity when go back to main activity from a fragment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can have a method in main activity which setting action bar , which you can call in Onresume of Main Activity .

example  **Main Activity Method** :

```
public void setActionBar(CharSequence title) {
         toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       }
```

Comment: i am not understand this code according to my source code because . i am not using toolbar,so please tell me according to my source code

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code in your fragment where from you back to MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    (AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("You Main Activity Title");

}
```

**or try this**

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("You Main Activity Title");

}
```

Comment: i am getting error in this code "AppCompatActivity" how to resolve